# Selenium | NoSuchWindowException

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Как можно обойти исключение NoSuchWindowException в Selenium ?

Необходимо постоянно обновлять страничку в браузере (5-10 секунд), иногда бывает перезагрузка затягивается и появляется страница "Пошло что то не так..."

Использую браузер Chrome.

Comment: Была задача похожего плана, надо было организовать циклический поиск элемента на странице. Нажимаем "Найти", проверяем наличие элемента, если нет, то опять жмём найти, если да, то клик по нему и выходим из цикла. Пишу на python, но надеюсь Вам пригодится это: `while driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'Ничего не найдено')]]"):
            driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.F5)
            time.sleep(5)
        else:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'То, что ищем')]]").click()
            print('Нашел и вышел из цикла')`

Comment: У меня проблема не с организацией поисков/обновлений и т.д.
А именно с исключением, когда есть окно браузера в котором ведётся работа и в какой то момент это окно перестаёт принимать команды.

Comment: Что если ещё раз обновить страницу тогда "Пошло что то не так..."? Если не помогает, то можно в так примерно: пока нет страницы "Пошло что то не так...", действовать по стандартной схеме, если появилась страница "Пошло что то не так...", то использовать `driver.get('https://site.com/')`, и просто заново открывать страницу.

Comment: @blindeStern в тот то и дело что у меня стояла команда на обновление страницы в случае исключения, но эту команду браузер не видит и ловлю ещё раз исключение. Не стал бодаться и  вылечил перезапуском драйвера.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать driver.navigate()

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Думаю, что в вашем случае подойдёт обработка данного исключения. В случае NoSuchWindowException вы просто перезапускаете WebDriver там где вам надо (открываете хром по новой). Используйте try catch.